# analyze two fields at a time with awk

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have a file with approximately 1 000 000 fields (tab delimited), but I need to incrementally look at fields in pairs to see if they are identical or different.

Here is 1 line of the file (abbreviated to 6 fields):

```
C G G G T A
```

I essentially need to print `1` if the pairs are identical and `2` if the pairs are different, so the output should be:

```
2 1 2
```

Is this possible with an awk for loop? Using `awk '{ if ($1==$2) print "1"; else print "2" }'` is simply not viable for the number of fields I have.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you can try,

```
echo "C G G G T A" | 
awk '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2){ 
        printf (i<NF-1?"%s ":"%s\n"), ($i==$(i+1)?1:2)
    }
}'
```

you get,

```
2 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with sed instead, probably much quicker (no splitting):

```
sed -r 's/(^\S|\s\S)\s/\1/g; s/(\S)\1/1/g; s/\S\S/2/g'
```

The first `s/` groups pairs by removing the space between them.

The second `s/` finds the matches.

The third `s/` converts the leftovers (mismatches).

Or the equivalent, if your `sed` does not have `-r`:

```
sed 's/^\(\S\)\s/\1/; s/\(\s\S\)\s/\1/g; s/\(\S\)\1/1/g; s/\S\S/2/g'
```